# jQuery AJAX PHP login form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, forms

I am trying to make a login form for a webapp.

**My login form**

```
<form class="col s12" method="post" action="#">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="username" type="text" name="name" required>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                 <input id="password" type="password" name="pas" required>
                 <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="error"></div>
        <div class="card-action">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="loginBtn" type="submit" value="Log In">Submit
                <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Button click script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#loginBtn').click(function() {

            var username=$("#username").val();
            var password=$("#password").val();
            var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
            if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "login.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(){ $("#loginBtn").val('Connecting...');},
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data) {
                            window.location.href = "application.php";
                        } else {
                            $('#loginCard').shake();    //Shake animation effect.
                            $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
            return false;

        });

    });
</script>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
    include("db.php");
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

        $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
        $password=msqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);
        $result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT uname FROM users WHERE uname='$username' and pass='$password'");
        $count=msqli_num_rows($result);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if($count==1) {

            $_SESSION['login_user']=$row['uname'];
            echo $row['uname']

        }

    }
?>
```

Whenever I click the submit button it redirects to the same page (index.php) by POST method. In the chrome developer tools, the submit data never gets sent to login.php, and I am not able to understand what's causing this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you include jquery itself?

Comment: This `$('#loginBtn').click(function()
{` should be `$('#loginBtn').click(function(event)
{ event.preventDefault();`

Comment: yes, I have included jQuery

Comment: @RobertRozas Can you explain why? also after changing as you suggested, its still not working.

Comment: Developer Console Snapshot [link](http://imgur.com/mdPdxzR")

Comment: `onclick='return false;'` added to the submit button

Comment: Hmm, everything works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bvzgv4fm/

Comment: @PrateekGupta, can you post the same snapshot but instead of the Network tab, show the Console Tab??

Comment: @RobertRozas [link](http://imgur.com/9SC5pMm)

Comment: You are still showing me the Network Tab @Prateek...i need a snapshot from the Console Tab..

Comment: remove form tag and button type submit.

Comment: remove type="submit" from your <button>

Comment: did you solve that OP? I see your code look good, it should work

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
<form class="col s12" method="post" action="#">
```

to

```
<form id="loginForm" class="col s12" method="post" action="#">
```

and instead of:

```
$('#loginBtn').click(function() {
```

you should have:

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Rest of the code here
});
```

or if the above does not work, you can try this one:

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function(e){
    // call a function for the ajax job
    return false;
});
```

Comment: doing this is not working. The problem is that page is not sending any request to login.php(Chrome Developer Console). On clicking submit it simply redirects to itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login").submit(function (e)
        {   

            var firstForm = $("#login").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: "login.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: firstForm,
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                //contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data)
                {                     
                    if ($.trim(data) === '1') {
                       window.location.href = 'display.php';                                 
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#msgbox').html('Invalid Email id or password.');
                        $('#msgbox').addClass("success").css("color", "red").fadeIn();
                        $('#msgbox').addClass("success").css("font-size", "15px");
                    }
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am inclined to think that the problem occurs because, by default, the call through ajax is xxxx (which means that the rest of the process continues and does not wait for the server's response).
You should use: 'async: false' as an additional parameter in the call to ajax::

```
$.ajax({
            url: "login.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: firstForm,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            //contentType: false,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data)
```